# Trying to Understand Why This Works / async return

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm creating an ASP.NET WebAPI 2 controller.  It works, but I'm confused why.  It seems I'm returning a List<..> and not a Task

Please explain to me why returning a List is correct.

```
public class AttendeePriceController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public async Task<List<AttendeePrice>> Get()
    {
        List<AttendeePrice> attendeesPriceList;
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            attendeesPriceList = await db.AttendeePrices.ToListAsync();
        }
        return attendeesPriceList;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `async` keyword transforms your method into a state machine. Part of that transformation is producing a `Task` that represents the method. When you "return" a value, the state machine completes that task with the value.

For more information, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) or the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, the docs does mention that you can returna primitive like I'm doing and then goes on to say "its a little odd" which I don't follow.  Am I essentially negating the async by returning the List directly?  Can you suggest a better way to return a task?  Sorry for not quite getting it (even after reading the docs several times)

Comment: It's odd because your code returns a type of `T` but the method signature has a return type of `Task<T>`. You're doing it correctly.

Comment: That's why I posted.  The code compiles and runs as I want, but not as I expect.  I'm wanting to wrap an async as part of the return (which may be wrong headed thinking).  My return needs to have the data at the second level of the JSON so I can't just return what EF gives me.

Comment: I'm not understanding you at all.

Comment: @PeterKellner: I'm still not clear about the JSON/EF comment; feel free to post a followup comment or another question if this answer isn't sufficient. I do have an older [unofficial `async` keyword FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html) that tries to explain *why* the `async`/`await` syntax was designed the way it was; that may be helpful.